# getting invalid async pipe while trying to get data from a async source

Tags: angular, asynchronous, kendo-grid

Im getting data from Async API,in my front end i have a grid Kendo UI,which i want to bind it with these data but in console, I see  invalidpipe[object object]

here is my service :

```
 getEventLog(ip) {
     return this.http.post(this.url_event_log, {}, {params: {id: ip}})
 }
```

and in my component i have:

```
this.service.getEventLog(id).subscribe(s => {
    this.eventlogs = s;
})
```

in my kendo grid i add the async pipe:

```
[data]="eventlogs| async"
```

Comment: You should pass the Observable directly into the async pipe. When you subscribe and unpack it into the variable `eventlogs`, it isn't async anymore and you could aswell just do `[data]="eventlogs"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either subscribe to the observable in the controller or use `async` pipe in the template. Not combine them.

**Option 1: subscribe in the controller**

Controller

```js
eventlogs: any;

this.service.getEventLog(id).subscribe(
  s => { this.eventlogs = s; },
  error => { }
);
```

Template

```html
[data]="eventlogs"
```

**Option 2: `async` pipe**

Controller

```js
eventlogs: Observable<any>;

this.eventlogs = this.service.getEventLog(id);
```

Template

```html
[data]="eventlogs | async"
```

And since you presumably wouldn't be using the `eventLogs` variable in the controller, it's better to use the `async` pipe since it takes care of potential memory leak issues.

Comment: In addition, the `eventlogs` should be of type `Observable`

Comment: i have done it and the error is gone, but may i ask why other parts of my browser is still freezing while my grid is getting async data?like my dropdownlist which is not async

Comment: That sounds like an entirely independent issue.

Comment: Whether you use the sync/async solution won't make your browser freeze

Comment: @ilmagnifico: I'm not familiar with KendoUI. If the dropdown are also Kendo, please check if the whole Kendo stack is refreshed when the async data is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The async pipe expects a stream, not the result from the stream.
It avoids you to explicitly subscribe to the stream into the component.

In your situation:

```
eventlogs$: Observable<any>;

constructor(private service: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.eventlogs$ = this.service.getEventLogs(id);
}
```

In your template :

```
[data]="eventlogs$ | async"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `async` pipe has to be used on asynchronous `Observable`s. The line `this.service.getEventLog(id).subscribe(...)` unpacks your Observable `this.service.getEventLog(id)` and stores it through the async callback `s => { this.eventlogs = s})` into the synchronous variable `eventlogs`. So you're in the end providing a synchronous variable into the async pipe.

#### Solution 1: Keep it async and provide the Observable

```
this.eventLogStream = this.service.getEventLog(id)
```

```
[data]="eventLogStream | async"
```

#### Solution 2: Keep it sync and remove the `async` pipe

```
this.service.getEventLog(id).subscribe(s=>

  {
   this.eventlogs=s;
   })
```

```
[data]="eventlogs"
```

Which solution you should prefer depends on how you're most likely to use the variable in other pieces of this code. Will you `pipe` and transform the same observable in other pieces of the code then stick with solution 1 and work with it as an async observable. If you're just interested in the data as it comes around then go for solution 2 and lean on Angular's change detection to update everything when the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try read about [Observables in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular) the issue was pretty obvious `async` pipe basically subscribe the Observable and **unsubscribe** automatically thats why recommended approach is to use async pipe.

And the reason why not working in your case was bcz you already subscribe the observable in your component.

```
 /*notice dollar sign at the end of variable that denotes the 
    variable as observable, also variable name should be camelCase.*/
 eventLogs$: Observable<any>;

/*http client always returns observable hence you could return
  that response without subscribing.*/
this.eventLogs$ = this.service.getEventLogs(id);
```

and in template just use async pipe it will subscribe stream and then unsubscribe authomaticlly.

```
[data]="eventLogs$ | async"
```